# How to solve "Firebase Phone Authentication Error: The SMS Code Has Expired"?

Tags: java, firebase-authentication, phone-number

I do Firebase authentication using phone number, in Android Java.

```java
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
   
            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            mVerificationInProgress = false;
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
            // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            mVerificationInProgress = false;
            // [END_EXCLUDE]

            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                // Invalid request
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId,
                               @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;
```

and do the signinwithcredential here using `PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);`

```java
    // Firebase Authentication
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (mVerificationInProgress && validatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber)) {
            startPhoneNumberVerification(phoneNumber);
        }
    }
```

The problem is, sometimes it says when I sign-in using SMS code:

> Firebase Phone Authentication Error: The SMS Code Has Expired

I used the same phone number, it works fine on one day, and it doesn't the other day. When it happens, I wait for a while and try again, it works.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Did you find any solution?
I am using google app signing and used SHA-1 of both upload and signing key in firebase.

Comment: @mdhz find solution i am facing similar problem if you got solution kindly share

Comment: @Meerz There was a problem in DB table, I rectified and it worked. If your app is interacting with an external DB, then I'd suggest looking for the query which is interacting with that table and see if it's actually executing it.